# Java compare List Array fastest way

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

I did a lot of research here, but did not found my case.

ListA=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
ListB=[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,10.23],[5,6,10],[1,3,4]

Result should be: 3

That means, the number group 1,2,3 is in the ListA , also the number Group 1,2,4 is completely in ListA, and also the 1,3,4 ist in ListA

I already have an if loop exapmle, but that takes too much time.

```
dreierKombis = [1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,7,8]
zahlen= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
treffer=0

for(ArrayList<Integer> singleDreierList : dreierKombis) {
    counter = 0;
    for(Integer dreierZahl : singleDreierList) {
        for(Integer ziehungsZahl : zahlen) {
            if(dreierZahl == ziehungsZahl) {
                counter = counter + 1;                          
            }
            if (counter == 3) {
                treffer = treffer +1;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Edit1:
But it's not really a performance improvement. Could this also be solved with multible CPU threads?

The Problem is, i have about 150 million dreierKombo and about 1000 number Groups. It takes 2h for the hole calculation.

Edit 2:
The Main Problem is the following:

1. Think in Lotto Numbers. Create all Lotto combination.
   There are 1-42 Numbers and you take 6 of them.
   In total you get over 5 Millions of combination.
2. For every single combination, create all 3er combination ...
   as example numbers could be : 1,4,9,15,22,40
   now create every 3er combination.
   1,4,9
   1,4,15
   1,4,22
   1,4,40
   1,9,15
   1,9,22
   ....
   ...

That was easy and very fast. I already have the code

3. Now take the history of lotto numbers drawn and compare with every of the 5 million combination.
   But not check, if all 6 Numbers was hit, just compare the 3er combinations.. And that is what takes so much time

Comment: Do you mean you want to count the number of lists in list 2 that are subsets of list 1? Can the lists contain duplicate numbers?

Comment: you might use `containsAll` ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-)). `if(zahlen.containsAll(singleDreierList)) counter++`

Comment: @Sweeper
No duplicates Numbers in the single 3 Number Group

Comment: For optimization questions, very often the limits are crucial. The question should state: Are there stated limits on the contents, e.g. are they always single digits? Perhaps never larger than 999? How large can `zahlen` be? How large can any single list in the combis list get? How many sublists can be in combis, maximum?

Comment: For example, if the sublists are guaranteed to always contain exactly 3 numbers, and, say, the numbers are guaranteed to exist between 0 and at most 2097151, you can compress a 3-list into a single `long`. This gets you to the algorithm of [1] Generate every 3-permutation of `zahlen` and set a boolean in a lookup table. [2] Loop through all dreierKombis and translate to a long. [3] Look it up in the table. Likely to be the fastest you can possibly make this code. (Also, sort). I can explain this in an answer but I need to know the limits first.

Comment: Given that no further required details are being posted by OP, voting to close this question for lack of detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `containsAll` as long as you don't care about duplicate numbers. Using streams, it can be written like this:

```java
var counter = listB.stream()
     .filter(list -> listA.containsAll(list))
     .count();
```

This could be your starting point.
Now, for the optimization, we would need to know more about your scenario. Checking just 5 lists once, like in your example, would obviously be fast. The question is if we need to optimize for how many times it would run, or for how big the lists are.

So for example, if listA and listB are very big, we could optimize it somewhat by converting `listA` to a `HashSet` on beforehand, and then using `.parallel()` on the stream, like this:

```java
var setA = new HashSet<>(listA);

var counter = listB.stream()
     .parallel()
     .filter(list -> setA.containsAll(list))
     .count();
```

If the function should be optimized to run in some kind of tight loop, then it might be better to look at the bigger picture around the function, and maybe integrate that tight loop into the stream-pipeline in order for it to better utilize the parallelization of `.parallel()`.

If the dataset is even bigger, then maybe you could look at ways to split the dataset in smaller chunks, so that you could split the workload across multiple machines (using map-reduce for example).

Comment: OP is asking about 'how to do it faster'. This is not faster. `containsAll` isn't some voodoo magical speed demon that does it in `O(1)`. The `stream` operation is a loop, and so is `containsAll`. `O(n*m)` just like OPs code. I don't know why this is being upvoted; it does not answer the question and cannot be salvaged. It shortcuts the inner check which is nice but the odds that this is now 'fast enough' are a _wild_ stab in the dark.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Lol, calm down. His initial question before the edits did not have the same emphasis on performance. Of course the answer can be salvaged (see my latest edit). Any guess on what is "fast enough" would be a stab in the dark, as OP didn't give any kind of performance numbers that we could compare against

Comment: The original question was specifically about performance. 'Lol, calm down' is not an appropriate response to an objective comment.

Comment: @rzwitserloot It was much more subtle, so I didn't see it at first. Your tone was certainly not objective, saying how my answer couldn't be salvaged and that it was just a wild stab in the dark. Try to write in a nicer and more helpful tone next time.

Answer (score 1):

To optimize the process, you can use a different approach by converting the lists into sets and then checking for set containment.

```
    int treffer = 0;

    Set<Integer> zahlenSet = new HashSet<>(zahlen);

    for (List<Integer> singleDreierList : dreierKombis) {
        boolean allPresent = true;
        for (Integer dreierZahl : singleDreierList) {
            if (!zahlenSet.contains(dreierZahl)) {
                allPresent = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (allPresent) {
            treffer++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(treffer);
```

Or you can use the containsAll method to simplify the containment check in your code.

```
  int treffer = 0;

    Set<Integer> zahlenSet = new HashSet<>(zahlen);

    for (List<Integer> singleDreierList : dreierKombis) {
        if (zahlenSet.containsAll(singleDreierList)) {
            treffer++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(treffer);
```

Or, in more readable way using java 8 streams:

```
int treffer = (int) dreierKombis.stream()
            .filter(zahlen::containsAll)
            .count();

    System.out.println(treffer);
```